# Erro ao usar o Case e Select no PL-SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

**Tenho este código:**

```
DECLARE
BEGIN

  SELECT p.categoria(
    CASE 
      WHEN p.categoria = 'A' THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('A')
      ELSE 2000 END
  )    
  FROM PRODUTO_TESTE2 p;

END;
```

**Mensagem de Erro:**

> Relatório de erros - ORA-06550: line 6, column 47: PL/SQL: ORA-00904:
>   : invalid identifier ORA-06550: line 4, column 3: PL/SQL: SQL
>   Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

**Estrutura da Tabela Produtos**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tente executar dessa forma o seu select:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN

  SELECT p.categoria,
    CASE WHEN p.categoria = 'A' THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('A')
    ELSE 2000 END   
  FROM PRODUTO_TESTE2 p;

END;
```